# how to evaluate equality of big O notation?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

I've been asked a question that seems strange to me. Given the following two equalities, which is true, and which is false (or are they both either true or false)?

1. O(n^2) = O(n^3)
2. O(n^3) = O(n^2)

To me, this question seems absurd, since O(f(n)) just means that for some time function T(n), lim as n -> infty of T(n) <= c * f(n).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/86096/219337, particularly the part where it says "When one asserts that E1=E2 where E1 and E2 are sets represented by expressions like the above, one should always interpret it to mean that E1⊆E2". So number 1 is correct and number 2 is false.

Answer (score 1):

O(f(n)) can be thought of as  the class of all functions whose growth is bounded above by f(n). Taking into account this, the two options are false.